# Estate accounts requiring 3 signature for withdrawal, is same required for deposits

Tags: united-states, bank-account, check, checking-account

We have an estate checking account in WV. It takes 3 of us to write a check.  Does it also take 3 signatures to deposit a check?

Comment: How many names are on to To line of the check? Are there ands or ors between the names?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I think it is rare to have a joint estate account, i.e. "Estate of (Decedent 1) and (Decedent 2)".

Comment: A quick call to your bank would answer this question.

Comment: @base64 The three signatures required may be of the three _executors_ of the estate of the same decedent. The jointness is in the signature authority not the jointness of estates.

Comment: @DilipSarwat That's for withdrawing money from an estate account. mhoran_psprep said "To" line of the check.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, to deposit you need the person to whom the check was given to to endorse. It doesn't matter how many names are on the account, what matters is how many names are on the check.